could not train my data using the json file
I've trained a model and downloaded its trained data which is in the format JSON, later im trying to use the json for training but it shows error as even though it correctly contains all the information. Please Someone help me!! [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/tB6Kfoyf.png)
Ive tried to correct the path file, tried downloading new set of data and added it to code many times, even used chatgpt and gemini still couldnt find the issue!

validate your file with a JSON linter program
